# Angular 5 .Net Core 2 project Does Not Work After Publish With 3rd Party js

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, publish

I have written an Angular 5 app in .Net Core 2, based from the Angular5 template.

I wrote this app initially and it worked fine, locally and when published using VS2017.

I then includded 3rd party js and css files for formatting to a specific format for use on a printer/copier device.

It still worked perfectly when run local.  However, when I publish using Visual Studio 2017, the angular features do not work at all (initial values do not display in textbox, no call on button click).

I am looking for help on fixing this, or even figuring out what is happening, as there is no message in the console nor errors reported anywhere.  I am an angular and .net core newb, so apologies if there are easy fixes or details that would help.

The 3rd party js files are in the header.  I have tried with the vendor.js file above them there, and in the index.cshtml as in the sample originally.

UPDATE: in the load, it clearly loads the angular-working version (i.e. outside of the applied frame from the 3rd party js, it is showing the default value I set) and then applies the frame which disables the Angular functionality.

[image: Initial load with default value]

[image: Final load after frame is applied]

TIA - Mike

Comment: Sounds like general troubleshooting issue to isolate the problem.  Did you publish all files ? Did you include files in the correct order ?  Do local and prod use vs2017 etc

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I did publish all the files.  I am using VS2017 for running it locally and publishing.  When you say "include in the correct order," what did you have in mind?  I have moved the 3rd party js around the angular js in a few efforts, with no change in result.